# Is there a way to find attributes of a module without installing it?

Tags: python, pip, package

I am building a static analysis tool for learning purposes and I am interested to know if there is a way to get information about modules / packages in python.
For example, If there is a module called ' requests' , I want to find all its methods (for example : Get, Post etc) and submodules.

I currently use modules such as 'inspect' and 'pkgutil' to find the attributes but they require 'requests' to be installed to give information about it. Is there a repository that maintains details about contents of a package in python ?

Thank you

Comment: Look at the documentation for the library?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). How would you analyze a piece of code without having access to it? If it is just the details you want, why build a tool at all?

Comment: @InSync *"How would you analyze a piece of code without having access to it?"* - By using that *"repository that maintains details about contents of a package"*.

Comment: @KellyBundy I wouldn't call that "static analysis"...

Comment: I understand the XY problem that @InSync pointed. I want to mimic an IDE's auto code fill feature. If a user types 'requests.' , a dropdown menu appears suggesting possible keywords (get, post etc.) . I assume they do it by maintaining a repository of commonly used modules. I am interested to look if there is a way to achieve the same without maintaining  a database but with real time retrieval. 

Thanks